# Why my Ubuntu (in virtualbox machine) freezes after some time even with a gaming computer?

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, google-chrome, games, freeze

I have a gaming computer (with GTX, intel core i7, etc...) with windows 10 and i have ubuntu (desktop 18.04 LTS) installed in a virtualbox machine. I gave 5 GB ram (my computer has 16 GB) and 4 CPU (i have in total 8) to the virtual machine. **When i boot its ok (the programs take about 6 seconds to open) but when i launch some programs like my IDE (vscode that its a bit heavy), google chrome (with 3 tabs), chrome dev tools, file manager, plus other background programs, the system starts getting slow and if open other program or do some operation that requires more performance it freezes (but only after a couple hours of coding because in the first hours the performance is great!) and i need to reboot.**

[image: Screenshot of task manager with the programs opened that i normally use while coding & debugging]

It looks like with the time, the updates, the packages that i've installed (i dont know how many but they are some...) and other things have also impact on performance because at the beginning the system used to run smother. And i also see that the machine is not making use of all the performance that i gave it (at least the ram).

This is very annoying because i need to be constantly reboot the system after freezing (the keyboard freezes too) and i love coding on ubuntu but im really considering use my host windows to do my coding and make use of all the performance that my machine have.

Any suggestion on how can i solve this?

Comment: The usual first step is to view `top` during sluggish behavior, to see which processes are hogging resources.

Comment: 18.04 is still somewhat new. 16.04 is a couple of years old and more stable. You might want to try 16.04 in the VM box.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix i was thinking in ubuntu 18.10, they say that has better performance...

Comment: Simply installing a newer kernel could also improve performance. Less pain doing it that way because it's easy to change kernel versions forwards and backwards.

Comment: So are you suggesting that i should install a newer kernel on my current ubuntu?